# How to handle DeadObjectException in android?

Tags: android

Sometimes I click the EditText in my application, the soft keyboard doesn't show, and the exception occurs(The exception doesn't always occur).
The exception log is:

```
W/InputMethodManagerService(  461): android.os.DeadObjectException

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.finishSession(IInputMethodSession.java:292)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.finishSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1357)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearClientSessionLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1348)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.clearCurMethodLocked(InputMethodManagerService.java:1374)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService.onServiceDisconnected(InputMethodManagerService.java:1393)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1120)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1134)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1111)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1197)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

    W/InputMethodManagerService(  461):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are not closing some resource before moving to the next screen